# using ngClass with bootstrap class as conditional screen size breakpoint detector

Tags: bootstrap-4, media-queries, ng-class, conditional-breakpoint

good day developers...is possible to apply  ngClass with the use of bootstrap class related to detection of screen sizes responsivnes.

Lets say i would like to apply an specific class to my template when a specifc viewport on m screen is detected

```
something like :

ngClass="{'my-class':'d-none d-sm-block d-md-none'}"
```

I mean applying a class if specific breakpoint is met.

Just want to avoid the use of media  queries

Comment: Why would you need to do this, since these classes already target a specific viewport. `d-sm-` only targets `sm-` sized devices. No need to add the class dynamically, that is handled by mediaqueries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write something like this.

```
<div [ngClass]="isSmallDevice() ? 'row m-2' : 'm-3'">
```

In your ts file, you can define the function.

```
isSmallDevice():boolean
{
  if (this.screenBreakPoint == Breakpoints.Medium ||
      this.screenBreakPoint == Breakpoints.Large || 
      this.screenBreakPoint == Breakpoints.XLarge)
  {
    return false;
  }
  
  return true;
}
```

screenBreakPoint is your defined BreakpointObserver